# Ember simple auth doesn't send auth header to api

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-simple-auth

I'm trying make authorization in my ember application.

Its working on client side, but ember doesn't attach Bearer token to api request.

My adapter

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import DataAdapterMixin from 'ember-simple-auth/mixins/data-adapter-mixin';

export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend(DataAdapterMixin, {
 host: 'http://localhost/money-app-api/web/app_dev.php/api',
 authorizer: 'authorizer:application'
});
```

My authorizer:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import OAuth2Bearer from 'ember-simple-auth/authorizers/oauth2-bearer';
const { isEmpty } = Ember;

export default OAuth2Bearer.extend({
authorize(data, block) {
const accessToken = data['access_token'];
if (!isEmpty(accessToken)) {
  block('Authorization', `Bearer ${accessToken}`);
}
```

accessToken in authorizer is exists and is correct.
My api is correct too, i tested it by Postman.

Comment: Please describe your question in the title.

Answer (score 2):

I am writing you a full tutorial please just follow that hope it works for you.

```
   //folders and files tree
    adapters
    --- application.js
    authenticators
    --- oauth2.js
    authorizers
    ---- oauth2-bearer.js
```

Adapters/application.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import DataAdapterMixin from 'ember-simple-auth/mixins/data-adapter-mixin';

export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend(DataAdapterMixin,{
  authorizer: 'authorizer:oauth2-bearer',
  host: 'http://localhost/money-app-api/web/app_dev.php',
  namespace: 'api'
});
```

authenticators/oauth2.js

```
import OAuth2PasswordGrant from 'ember-simple-auth/authenticators/oauth2-password-grant';

export default OAuth2PasswordGrant.extend({
  serverTokenEndpoint: 'http://localhost/money-app-api/web/app_dev.php/token'
});
```

authorizers/oauth2-bearer.js

```
export { default } from 'ember-simple-auth/authorizers/oauth2-bearer';
```

so now in your route, `application.js`,  you are able to use the following code: this is just for demo purpose you need to modify as you need.

```
  this.get('session').authorize('authorizer:oauth2-bearer', (headerName, headerValue) => {
          headers[headerName] = headerValue;
        });
```

I am writing an authentication in route/application.js to clarify more. in this example I am getting Account and User information based on session which has already authenticated .

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import ApplicationRouteMixin from 'ember-simple-auth/mixins/application-route-mixin';
import config from '../config/environment';

export default Ember.Route.extend(ApplicationRouteMixin, {

  model() {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      account: new Ember.RSVP.Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        if (!this.get('session.isAuthenticated')) {
          resolve({});
          return;
        }

        let store = this.store,
          session = this.get('session');

        let headers = {};

        this.get('session').authorize('authorizer:oauth2-bearer', (headerName, headerValue) => {
          headers[headerName] = headerValue;
        });

        return Ember.$.ajax(config.apiUrl + '/api/account', {
          headers: headers
        }).then(data => {
          if (data) {
            store.pushPayload(data);
            resolve(store.peekRecord('user', data.data.id));
          } else {
            reject({});
            session.invalidate();
          }
        }).fail(() => {
          session.invalidate();
        });
      })
    });
  },
  sessionAuthenticated() {
    this.refresh();
    this._super();
  }
});
```

I hope, this can solve your problem.

an important tip:

````
 The REST adapter allows your store to communicate with an HTTP server by
  transmitting JSON via XHR. Most Ember.js apps that consume a JSON API
  should use the REST adapter.
  ### Headers customization
  Some APIs require HTTP headers, e.g. to provide an API key. Arbitrary
  headers can be set as key/value pairs on the `RESTAdapter`'s `headers`
  object and Ember Data will send them along with each ajax request.
  ```app/adapters/application.js
  import DS from 'ember-data';
  export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    headers: {
      "API_KEY": "secret key",
      "ANOTHER_HEADER": "Some header value"
    }
  });
  ```
  `headers` can also be used as a computed property to support dynamic
  headers. In the example below, the `session` object has been
  injected into an adapter by Ember's container.
  ```app/adapters/application.js
  import DS from 'ember-data';
  export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    headers: Ember.computed('session.authToken', function() {
      return {
        "API_KEY": this.get("session.authToken"),
        "ANOTHER_HEADER": "Some header value"
      };
    })
  });
  ```
````

[Source](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v2.7.0/addon/adapters/rest.js#L1320)

Comment: I arleady have it and its working for me. But my problem is ember doesn't attach header to json adapter

Comment: I just added a tip for sending headers in adapter, that should help your problem. give it a try .

Answer (score 0):

My only problem was that i have not `authorization` in my accept headers in api

`allow_headers: ['origin', 'X-Custom-Auth', 'Content-Type', 'Authorization']`

That is strange, because when tested by Postman all was working.